# How to score after question is answered? React js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to score points after the answer is answered correctly or wrongly. Possibly is something easy to see but I'm still new to react ... sorry;/ I will appreciate any help.

```
const handleOption = () => {
 if (isClick[countQuestion - 1]) return;
 let newdata = [...isClick];
 newdata[countQuestion - 1] = true;
 setIsClick(newdata);};

<div className="options-display">
{questions.options.map((options) => {
   return (
      <button
         className={`btn-option ${
              isClick[countQuestion - 1]
              ? options === questions.answer ? "correct" : "incorrect" 
              :""
            }`}
            key={options}
            onClick={handleOption}
          >
           {options}
          </button>
         );
       })}</div>

 export default Question;
```

And that's my sec component=child

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function Score(){

const [score,setScore]=useState(0)
return (
    <div>
      <h1>Your score is: {score}</h1>
    </div>)}

 export default Score;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a hook called `useEffect` to run code after a component has been rendered. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function Score() {
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isClick[countQuestion - 1]) {
      let newScore = score + 1;
      setScore(newScore);
    }
  }, [isClick]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Your score is: {score}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This one work if a user clicks on any button but how to specify a point for the correct answer only? My plan is to give a point if the answer is selected correctly however if not user sees a penalty of minus 1 point.